# Javascript: Read remote file as binary

Tags: javascript, html, file, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to grab a URL on a page via a Chrome Extension. I then need to read this file as binary data before posting it to an external API. I'm wondering how to accomplish this, and if it is even possible. The file type would be PDF, Word Doc or text file typically. We are working with Resumes'.

I have starting reading about File objects and the FileReader, but my initial tests have returned no luck. Anyone have any examples that I could use as a starting off point?

If you could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely can do this. A FileReader should have the method readAsArrayBuffer, which will give you an ArrayBuffer, which you can then inspect by creating a Uint8Array or a DataView on which you can call methods like getUint32, etc.

Comment: It appears this only works with local files. I am attempting to read a remote file that is hosted on a URL.

Comment: Oh, then set xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer' and then the response for your xhr object will be an ArrayBuffer

Comment: What about the Cross Domain Policy? It appears this will prevent the JS from fetching the file. My goal is to read a remote file into a binary string, then send it to a 3rd party API. I would like to keep this 100% JS/HTML

Comment: You can add host permissions in the manifest for the extension so that it can ignore cross domain issues. It's definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to take a look at [jBinary](https://github.com/jDataView/jBinary)